# how to upload phonegap app to windows store

Tags: windows-store-apps

hi I developed a Phonegap application which supports android,IOS and windows.Its working fine in android and IOS. Now I want to deploy the windows app into windows app store. Can you guys suggest me how to deploy and If you find any links please give me.Thanks in advance